# How do JSP tag files and libraries work?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I've been learning about JSPs and came across tag files and libraries. I know that they are custom actions and useful for pointing out errors instead of using JavaBeans for example, but I still don't understand how they work. Lets say for example you do:

```
<jsp:directive.attribute name = "amount" required = "true" />
```

And later, assuming that `calc` is defined using `jsp:useBean`, `amount` can be used by:

```
<c:set target="${calc}" property = "amount" value ="${amount}" />
```

But what happens behind the scenes?

Comment: Note that all `<jsp:xxx>` tags other than `<jsp:include>` are discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

`${calc}` represents value of variable `calc` which may be there in pageCOntext,request,session,Servletcontext

By the statement

```
<c:set target="${calc}" property = "amount" value ="${amount}" />
```

it will store value in `calc` var's `amount` represented by value

Behind the scene it would be

```
calc.setAmount(amount);
```

Comment: i just want to know what are tag files?

Comment: tag files are like grouped HTML/jsp code which is frequently used so we are putting them in a tag and reusing

Answer (score 0):

Tag files are custom tag handlers which are written in JSP. These jsp are converted to java tag handlers by the JSP compiler.